# error while running Popen

Tags: python

I am running into following error when trying to run a command using Popen,what is wrong here?

```
cmd = "export COMMANDER_SERVER=commander.company.com"
Pipe = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(output, error) = Pipe.communicate()
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ectool.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_ectool.py", line 13, in main
    Pipe = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by running that command? Even if it worked, the command would have no effect on anything. You'd just be setting an environment variable in the child process which would be lost as soon as the child process exits.

Comment: That's not how you set environment variables from Python. Use `os.environ['COMMANDER_SERVER'] = 'commander.company.com'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to separate the arguments from the command and give a `list` to Popen.
2. As Kenster's comment said, even if your command worked, you would only succeed in modifying an environmental variable inside a sub-shell not the main shell.
3. You will not be able run run `export` this way, because it is not a program. It is a bash built-in.

Here is an example of a command that does work, with the correct semantics.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

cmd = "echo COMMANDER_SERVER=commander.company.com"
Pipe = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(output, error) = Pipe.communicate()
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

merlin2011's answer is incorrect regarding the command string for Popen (point #1). From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> *args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string.

As other people have stated, the environment variable will not be saved. For that, you need to use `os.environ['VARNAME'] = value`. If you want to use other bash builtins, then you must pass `shell=True` as an argument to `Popen`.

Comment: Also from the docs: `Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.`

Comment: Furthermore: `On Unix, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done if not passing arguments to the program.`

Comment: Given his original code and error messages, I assumed he was on a Unix-like system.